# how to upload local project to FloydHub server

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm using floydhub server for the first time and I wanted to execute the code which is available on my local system. I tried adding this directory to floydhub server using floyd add 'filename' but it gave me an error.

WHen I tried **floyd --help**. I get:

```
Usage: floyd [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

    Floyd CLI interacts with FloydHub server and executes your commands. More
      help is available under each command listed below.

    Options:
      -h, --host TEXT  Floyd server endpoint
      -v, --verbose    Turn on debug logging
      --help           Show this message and exit.

    Commands:
      clone    Download the code for the experiment to the...
      data     Subcommand for data operations
      delete   Delete project runs
      info     Prints detailed info for the run
      init     Initialize new project at the current dir.
      login    Log into Floyd via Auth0.
      logout   Logout of Floyd.
      logs     Print the logs of the run.
      output   Shows the output url of the run.
      run      Run a command on Floyd.
      status   View status of all or specific run.
      stop     Stop a run before it can finish.
      upgrade  Upgrade floyd command line
      version  Prints the current version of the CLI
```

How can I push my local code to floydhub server? I don't have github url. 
WHen I tried running the python file from floyd cli then I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: './.env/src/xgboost/cub/examples/block/example_block_radix_sort.cu'
```

How can I execute my local code on floydhub server?

Files which I have :

1. Dataset folder which contains 2 folders with images
2. source python file
3. floyd_requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `floyd run` command to upload the code and start your instance.

If you have the too many files error you need to add some directories to `.floydignore` file: https://docs.floydhub.com/faqs/job/#i-get-too-many-open-files-error-when-i-run-my-project

This will ensure that directories that are not required will not get uploaded to FloydHub.

You can try running the quickstart from here for a full end-to-end example: https://docs.floydhub.com/getstarted/quick_start/